# Javascript Increment by 1

Tags: javascript, increment

I'm new to JavaScript and I wrote code that invokes virtual users:

```
function User(){
    this.name = ""
    this.life = 100
    this.givingLifeToAplayer = function(PlayerName){
        PlayerName.life += 1
        console.log(this.name + " gave 1 life to " + PlayerName.name)
    }

}
var Yani = new User()
var jenny = new User()
var Robert = new User()
Yani.name = "Yani"
jenny.name = "Jenny"
Robert.name = "Robert";
Yani.givingLifeToAplayer(jenny)
console.log("Yani has " + Yani.life + " Jenny has " + jenny.life)
jenny.givingLifeToAplayer(Robert)
console.log("Jenny has " + jenny.life + " is the biggest score to " + Robert.life)
```

How can I increment the `life` by 1 every time when a user pass `life` to another user?

Comment: You have not asked a question

Answer (score 0):

You were doing it right. `PlayerName` is a reference to the object in the parameter of call in `User.givingLifeToAplayer`. When you edit the reference, you edit the two objects (the object in argument and `PlayerName`). The same when you edit the original object.

So... you did it. But your code is more readable so:

```
function User(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.life = 100;
    this.addLifeTo = function(player) {
        player.life ++; // increment operator
        console.log(this.name + " gave 1 life to " + player.name);
    }
}
var Yani = new User("Yani"),
    Jenny = new User("Jenny"),
    Robert = new User("Robert");

Yani.addLifeTo(Jenny);
console.log("Yani has " + Yani.life + ". Jenny has " + Jenny.life);
Jenny.addLifeTo(Robert);
console.log("Jenny has " + Jenny.life + "; it's the biggest score to " + Robert.life);
```

Answer (score 0):

Klaider Klai thank you for your answer
I want to increase the score +1 every time when a player pass score to another player, because I can see `Jenny` is passing 1 point to `Robert` but Robet's score is not increasing by 1.
Many thanks